# "undefined" is not a function setting listener on array of checklist

Tags: javascript

I have an array of checklists I am creating in a table that all have the same class `unitCheckbox`, so that I can find them in the document, as follows:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-fixedheader" style="margin-bottom:-5px">
<thead>
<tr><th width="40%">Serial</th><th width="25%">Type</th><th width="35%">Included</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td width="40%">A2F0J000</td>
    <td width="25%">Base</td>
    <td align="center" width="35%"><input id="A2F0J000" type="checkbox" name="Base" value="A2F0J000" class="unitCheckbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="40%">A2F0J001</td>
    <td width="25%">Base</td>
    <td align="center" width="35%"><input id="A2F0J001" type="checkbox" name="Base" value="A2F0J001" class="unitCheckbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="40%">A2F0J002</td>
    <td width="25%">Client</td>
    <td align="center" width="35%"><input id="A2F0J002" type="checkbox" name="Client" value="A2F0J002" class="unitCheckbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="40%">A2F0J003</td>
    <td width="25%">Client</td>
    <td align="center" width="35%"><input id="A2F0J003" type="checkbox" name="Client" value="A2F0J003" class="unitCheckbox"></td>
</tr>
...
```

I then try to set a listener for `change` on all of these checkboxes as follows:

```
var unitCheckboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('unitCheckbox');

for(c in unitCheckboxes){
    if(unitCheckboxes.hasOwnProperty(c)){
        unitCheckboxes[c].addEventListener("change", function(){

                alert("hi");
                }, false);
    }
}
```

However, I am getting an error in the console:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'unitCheckboxes[c].addEventListener("change", function(){
                // Do something
            }, false)')
```

Here is a simple [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2QCDG/3/) of the error.

Comment: I don’t see any error in console in Firefox … but anyway, why use that kind of for loop and `hasOwnProperty` anyway? `getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection, and you can safely loop over that with a “normal” for loop going from 0 to `length-1` – see http://jsfiddle.net/2QCDG/4/

Comment: I get the error in Safari and Chrome, I don't have Firefox to test it out there.  But I can try to use a "normal" loop there.

Comment: See my edit to previous comment, I added a fiddle that shows using a “normal” for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is the problem.  When cycling through, one of the properties ends up being length and it blows up when you do unitCheckboxes['length'].

Change your loop to -

```
for(var i = 0; i < unitCheckboxes.length; i++){
    (function(i){
        unitCheckboxes[i].addEventListener("change", function(){
            alert(i);
        }, false);
    })(i);
}
```

Here's a fiddle - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2QCDG/9/)

Comment: Keep functions out of loops.

Comment: @EasyBB: That’s what’s called a closure, and is actually _necessary_ here (well, in this specific example anyway) – because without the anonymous function wrapped around the whole thing, the `alert` would only bring up the _final_ value of `i` – 4 – for each of the checkboxes afterwards, see http://jsfiddle.net/2QCDG/10/

Comment: @CBroe: True, but you'd have the best of both worlds if you defined the function outside and gave it a name. It doesn't really need to be re-created every iteration.

Comment: Yes I know its a closure. Its an IIFE to be exact. So id rather use a named function outside the loop

Comment: Yes, but if you want to access the “index” of the checkbox, the current `i` value, you need the closure. (And yes, I know there would be other ways to get the checkbox index.)

Comment: You shouldnt need the index for the eventListener its a unique element being added it iteration so no index needed im pretty sure. Run it the way I have it and let me know

Comment: Its all good you can add the closure like stated but the main function outside and pass I as an argument as well.

Comment: _“You shouldnt need the index”_ – I’m just saying _if_ you wanted to make use of it, like alerting “You clicked checkbox number 3” … not that you absolutely _need_ it no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

To add to VtoCorleones post but keep functions out of loops. So do this

```
function checkBoxFunc(b){
  b.addEventListener('click', function(){
     //js here
 }, false);
}
for (i=0; i <unitCheckboxes.length; i++){
    checkBoxFunc(unitCheckBoxes[i]);
 }
//also if using eventListener add polyfill before all of this
if(!document.addEventListener){
  document.addEventListener=function(type, fn){
    document.attachEvent("on"+type, fn);
 };
}
```

I only say this because for one its cleaner and now we have cross broswer compatibility.  Hope this helped a little. Just wanted to explain my comment a little more

Comment: You got a syntax error in there, `)` in the second last line has no place being there.

Comment: I probably do lol im on my phone and it doesnt like to work with me! Thank you for pointing it out